# WDS - Initial configuration using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2, wds

I am installing WDS on Windows server 2012 R2. I want to use PowerShell from start to finish. I can install the feature, but I cant't find a way to do the initial configuration from the shell.  This is normally done from ServerManager, but that's what I want to avoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick answer: No you cannot use Powershell.

Long answer:  I just installed WDS role in 2012R2 in a lab, with MDT2013.  WDS still uses the non-powershell, but confusingly similar in syntax **wdsutil.exe** for configuration.

I use Powershell in lieu of CMD.exe for most things, which gets REALLY confusing at times.

Examples:

```
/> wdsutil.exe /get-namespace /namespace:domain


/> wdsutil.exe /intitialize-server /server:servername /reminst:"D:\RemoteInstall"
```

Start with `wdsutil.exe /AllHelp` and take notes so you don't have to learn all of it's quirks.

Comment: I'll go for wdsutil.exe there, and then Powershell for the rest... :)